# EXC_BAD_ACCESS runtime exception when accessing the structure variables->Objective C

Tags: objective-c

```
test.h
-------
struct session {
    int a;
    int c;
    int b;
};
struct session* pEvent;
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface test : NSObject {

}
-(void)set;
@end

test.m
--------

#import "test.h"


@implementation test

-(id)init{
    pEvent->a=10;
    pEvent->c='a';
    pEvent->b=20;
    return self;
}
-(void)set{

    //struct session* pEvent;
    //pEvent->a=10;
    //pEvent->c='a';
    //pEvent->b=20;
    NSLog(@"a:%d c:%c b:%d",pEvent->a,pEvent->c,pEvent->b);

}

@end
```

I am getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` runtime exception and the debugger points to `pEvent->a` when

declared in both the ways inside the init method or inside the set method.

Do i need to intialise the structure as `pEvent = new session;`? If declared like this I'm

getting new undeclared error. Then I tried with `pEvent = [session new];` and `pEvent = [[session alloc]init];` If declared like this i'm getting session undeclared error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
struct session {
    int a;
    int c;
    int b;
} pEventStruct;
struct session* pEvent = &pEventStruct;
```

You got bad access as you have not allocated memory for `pEvent`, just declared a pointer.

Comment: Command /Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

This is the error i'm getting!!

ld: duplicate symbol _pEvent in /structure/build/structure.build/Debug/structure.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/test.o and /structure/build/structure.build/Debug/structure.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/structure.o

when declared as you said me to do. We used declare assign the structure pointer to point to the structure variable in C.But i dont know why its showing me this error.

Comment: test.h and test.m are where i have declared and defined the structure. And structure.m is where the main function is and from where i'm calling the test.m's function.

Comment: Do you have any other global variable name pEvent? Try to rename it and check whether that is the problem.

Comment: I didnt have any other global variable with that name.When i declared struct session* pEvent = &pEventStruct as global i got the error.when i declared this and used in a function set its working fine and giving me the correct output.Thanks.

Comment: It is possible that some library used by you have declared a global with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

For a global structure you don't want a pointer unless you malloc, so like so:

```
struct session {
    int a;
    int c;
    int b;
};
struct session pEvent;
```

Then `pEvent.a = 10` to access.

A better design might be to use object-oriented patterns like singletons or a class method to access your data structure, however.

Comment: It works fine when declared as a structure variable.In c we could able to access the structure through pointers by making it point to the structure through the structure variable as told by taskinoor in the example below.But i could not make to happen the same in objective C.Its throwing me an error.